# How to run in sequence queries in SQL server if the previous one is finished with no errors?

Tags: sql-server

I have created several queries in SQL Server to obtain a report, but I would like to run them automatically in sequence if the first query runs and finish without errors.
Please have a look at the example posted:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WITH cte AS (SELECT[WO], row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY WO order by [WO]) AS [rn],
     [WeekDay],[now] FROM [MESF_1].[dbo].[Server])
DELETE cte WHERE [rn] > 1 and (DATEDIFF(DAY,[NOW],GETDATE())) < 20 and [Weekday] is not null
USE [MESF_1]
GO
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
UPDATE [MESF_1].[dbo].[Server]
   SET [Time] = Format ([NOW],'HH:mm:ss')
 WHERE [Time] is null
GO
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
UPDATE [MESF_1].[dbo].[Server]
   SET [WeekDay] = case datepart(WEEKDAY,CONVERT(date,[NOW],103)) 
   when 1 then'Sunday' When 2 then 'Monday' When 3 then'Tuesday' When 4 then 'Wednesday' 
   when 5 then 'Thursday' when 6 then 'Friday' when 7 then 'Saturday' end
   FROM [MESF_1].[dbo].[Server]
   where [WeekDay] is null
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The queries are separated by dashes.
Thank you in advance

Comment: You can use [TRY .. CATCH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) within a script, or check the value of the [@@ERROR function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/error-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), BUT those are 3 separate scripts with no relation between them. `GO` is a keyword recognized only by SSMS or sqlcmd, used to separate scripts for execution. This is little different from executing each script separately.

Comment: If the first succeeds, and the second fails, what do you want to happen to the operations that happened in the first?

Comment: *"The queries are separated by dashes. Thank you in advance"* They aren't just separated by that, they're separated into separate batches with `GO`; far more important than them visually separated with a line of dashes (`-`).

Comment: @Lamu If there is an error I would like to stop the process. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this.  By checking @@rocount>0 after the first UPDATE, if the the first update doesn't affect any rows, then the following 2 UPDATE statements never run.  To continue executing after an exception the DML statements are placed inside Try/Catch blocks.

```
USE [MESF_1];
set nocount on;

begin try
    WITH cte AS (
        SELECT [WO], [WeekDay],[now],
               row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY WO order by [WO]) AS [rn]
        FROM [dbo].[Server])
    DELETE cte 
    WHERE [rn] > 1 
          and (DATEDIFF(DAY,[NOW],GETDATE())) < 20 
          and [Weekday] is not null;

    if @@rowcount>0
        begin
            UPDATE [dbo].[Server]
               SET [Time] = Format ([NOW],'HH:mm:ss')
            WHERE [Time] is null;

            UPDATE [dbo].[Server]
               SET [WeekDay] = case datepart(WEEKDAY,CONVERT(date,[NOW],103)) 
                               when 1 then'Sunday' When 2 then 'Monday' When 3 then'Tuesday' 
                               When 4 then 'Wednesday' when 5 then 'Thursday' when 6 then 'Friday'
                               when 7 then 'Saturday' end
            WHERE [WeekDay] is null;
        end
end try
begin catch
    print ('There was an exception thrown');

    /* Logging, raiserror, throw*/
    /* rollback (if transaction requires*/
end catch
```

Answer (score 0):

did you means this

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT[WO], row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY WO order by [WO]) AS [rn],
 [WeekDay],[now] FROM [MESF_1].[dbo].[Server])
DELETE cte WHERE [rn] > 1 and (DATEDIFF(DAY,[NOW],GETDATE())) < 20 and [Weekday] is 
not null
USE [MESF_1]
GO
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
if @@Error=0 then
begin
UPDATE [MESF_1].[dbo].[Server]
SET [Time] = Format ([NOW],'HH:mm:ss')
WHERE [Time] is null
GO
end
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
if @@Error=0 then
begin
UPDATE [MESF_1].[dbo].[Server]
SET [WeekDay] = case datepart(WEEKDAY,CONVERT(date,[NOW],103)) 
when 1 then'Sunday' When 2 then 'Monday' When 3 then'Tuesday' When 4 then 'Wednesday' 
when 5 then 'Thursday' when 6 then 'Friday' when 7 then 'Saturday' end
FROM [MESF_1].[dbo].[Server]
where [WeekDay] is null
end
```

Comment: It returned errors. {(20 rows affected)
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'then'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near 'HERE'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'if'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'then'.

Completion time: 2020-10-02T11:51:10.2169359-06:00}

Comment: I hope  haven't any Error in next excute